# Angular2 : Difference between Host and HostListener

Tags: angular

I was wondering what's the difference between doing :

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'input',
  host: {
    '(window:resize)': 'onResize($event)'
  }
})
class InputDirective {
  onResize(event:Event) {
     ...
  }
}
```

and

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'input'
})
class InputDirective {
  @HostListener('window:resize', [$event])
  onResize(event:Event) {
     ...
  }
}
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41318575/angular-2-typescript-input-output-or-input-output and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40661325/why-is-input-decorator-preferred-over-inputs

Comment: After going through the questions mentioned by @yurzui, prefer '@HostListener' over `host` as in angular style guide ?